# Long titles on closed questions in search results hide closed status indicator

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, closed-questions

The closed status indicator is included as part of the text when the title for search results is passed through the truncation method, causing it to occasionally become hidden when the title of a closed question is particularly lengthy.

For example, [searching for a bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+front+page+user+name) produces the following closed question as a result:

[image: clipped title of close question obscuring closed status indicator]

While there are other indications that this particular question is closed (including that it says so in the title tooltip), it seems accidental that the status indicator gets cut off.

I'm not sure if the current layout of the search results necessitates the truncation anymore, but aside from just not truncating the title at all, it would be good if the status was at least always visible after the ellipsis in these cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, we'll append the suffix after the truncation for the link.  Thanks!